# SkLearn: Feature Union with a dictionary and text data

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I have a DataFrame like:

```
     text_data                worker_dicts                  outcomes

0    "Some string"           {"Sector":"Finance",             0
                              "State: NJ"}                   
1    "Another string"        {"Sector":"Programming",         1
                              "State: NY"}
```

It has both text information, and a column that is a dictionary. (The real `worker_dicts` has many more fields). I'm interested in the binary outcome column.

What I initially tried doing was to combine both `text_data` and `worker_dict`,  crudely concatenating both columns, and then running Multinomial NB on that:

```
    df['stacked_features']=df['text_data'].astype(str)+'_'+df['worker_dicts']
    stacked_features = np.array(df['stacked_features'])
    outcomes = np.array(df['outcomes'])
    text_clf = Pipeline([('vect', TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english'), ngram_range = (1,3)), 
   ('clf', MultinomialNB())])
    text_clf = text_clf.fit(stacked_features, outcomes)
```

But I got very bad accuracy, and I think that fitting two independent models would be a better use of data than fitting one model on both types of features (as I am doing with stacking).

How would I go about utilizing Feature Union? `worker_dicts` is a little weird because it's a dictionary, so I'm very confused as to how I'd go about parsing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dictionary entries are categorical as they appear to be in your example, then I would create different columns from the dictionary entries before doing additional processing.

```
new_features = pd.DataFrame(df['worker_dicts'].values.tolist())
```

Then `new_features` will be its own dataframe with columns `Sector` and `State` and you can one hot encode those as needed in addition to TFIDF or other feature extraction for your `text_data` column. In order to use that in a pipeline, you would need to create a new transformer class, so I might suggest just applying the dictionary parsing and the TFIDF separately, then stacking the results, and adding [OneHotEncoding](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) to your pipeline as that allows you to specify columns to apply the transformer to. (As the categories you want to encode are strings you may want to use [LabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html) class instead of OneHotEncoder class for the encoding transformation.)

If you want to just use TFIDF on all of the columns individually with a pipeline, you would need to use a nested Pipeline and FeatureUnion set up to extract columns as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895434/how-to-make-pipeline-for-multiple-dataframe-columns/47896417#47896417).

If you have your one hot encoded features in dataframes X1 and X2 as described below and your text features in X3, you could do something like the following to create a pipeline. (There are many other options, this is just one way)

```
X = pd.concat([X1, X2, X3], axis=1)

def select_text_data(X):
    return X['text_data']

def select_remaining_data(X):
    return X.drop('text_data', axis=1)


# pipeline to get all tfidf and word count for first column
text_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('column_selection', FunctionTransformer(select_text_data, validate=False)),
    ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer())
])


final_pipeline = Pipeline([('feature-union', FeatureUnion([('text-features', text_pipeline), 
                               ('other-features', FunctionTransformer(select_remaining_data))
                              ])),
                          ('clf', LogisticRegression())
                          ])
```

(MultinomialNB won't work in the pipeline because it doesn't have `fit` and `fit_transform` methods)

Comment: This is a very informative answer! In the meanwhile, I ended up using Pandas to do some stuff: First, I turned each of the `worker_dicts` keys (`Sector`, `State`) into columns, and then I used one-hot encoding on each  of those columns. Then, for both columns, I stacked all the sparse matrices that were outputs of one-hot encoding. Let `X1` and `X2` denote stacked sparse arrays comprising of the one-hot encoding of `Sector` and `State`, respectively. Let `X3` denote the vectorized `text_data` column.

Comment: Given the modifications to the data - where we now have `X1`, `X2`, `X3` - would you make any edits to the two methods you suggested?